# What’s the difference between the following property declarations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What are differences between these?

1. `@interface { id value )` , No `@property`.
2. `@interface { id value )` , `@property id value;` and `@synthesis value;`
3. `@interface ( /*    */ )` , `id value` in `@implementation`
4. `@interface ( /*    */ )` , `id value` out of `@implementation`
5. the others, if you think the others good example

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is this? Is it supposed to be code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

1. Instance variable with no compiler-generated accessors. Can be accessed from the class directly, can be accessed from the outside only by breaking encapsulation (`foo->value`).
2. Regular class property (= instance variable with accessors). Can be accessed both from the class and from the outside using accessors, can be accessed from the class directly.
3. If you mean `@implementation {id value;}`, this is a private instance variable. Very much like (1), only the variable is hidden from the public header. This is a recent addition AFAIK.
4. Not a class variable, shared by all instances.

There’s also one more option, private class property declared in the implementation file:

```
@interface YourClass ()
@property(retain) id foo;
@end

@implementation YourClass
@synthesize foo;
@end
```

This gives you nice compiler-generated accessors without the variable having to be exposed in the public header. To wrap things up, I usually use regular properties (number 2) for public stuff and properties declared in a class extension (number 5) for private stuff.

Comment: 3) Your answer is only correct if the variable is declared within curly brackets directly following the `@implementation` keyword. My reading of the question was that it was simply a global variable declared within the @implementation block, and would be treated the same as 4). Either way, you may want to clarify which one you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance variable (an ivar):

```
@interface sampleClass : superclass
{
     NSUInteger sampleIvar;
}
```

This is a private iVar:

```
@interface sampleClass : superclass
{
     @private
     NSUInteger sampleIvar;
}
```

This are a properties:

```
@property (nonatomic,copy)   NSString  *sampleCopiedProperty;
@property (atomic,copy)      NSString  *sampleAtomicCopiedProperty;
@property (nonatomic,retain) yourClass *sampleRetainProperty;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL       sampleAssignProperty;
```

Properties are iVars that have their getters and setters generated by a compiler. properties save you time by reducing boilerplate code and let other classes access ivars of your class.

iVars have file scope, properties can be accessed from other objects.

Note: You can create properties and then specify the name of the setter, getter and even the iVar.

Note: If you use NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary etc. you MUST write the setter yourself and use `mutableCopy` otherwise the compiler generated setter will use `copy` on the new value which will result in a non mutable version.

in iOS 5.0 in addition to readOnly, atomic, nonatomic, copy, retain, assign etc. a new keyword `__weak` will be added to property definitions which helps you free memory for circular references.